# How to check if variable is still valid or std::move was used on it?

Tags: c++, move, undefined-behavior

I am aware that after using `std::move` the variable is still valid, but in an unspecified state.

Unfortunately, recently I have come across several bugs in our code base where a function was accessing the moved variable, and weird things were happening. These issues were extremely hard to track down.

Is there any compiler option (in clang) or any way to throw an error either during runtime or compilation?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  IMHO, this should be handled with code review and training people to use moved objects unless they set them to some known state first.

Comment: There is some warning which reports that variable can be used after it was moved. Just add compiler flags so it is reported as an error.

Comment: @MarekR That's exactly what the question is asking :p *which* flags?

Comment: And at what point does the fact that the object was moved get lost? I don't expect the compiler can catch them all.

Comment: Sorry looks like this warning is [still under development](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-use-after-move.html) and it is part of "Extra Clang Tools".

Comment: just curious, the only problematic cases are those that expliticly call `std::move`, or do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe this should be part of the standard as a warning. Like [[no_discard]]

Comment: The statement not quite valid.. if variable is of primitive type, move operation is equivalent of copy. Only for class-types with defined constructors there is something different. And technically, replacing invalid state with a custom tombstone is possible, e.g. for debug build. And we have `std::optional`

Comment: `std::move` has no effect whatsoever on the state of the object that it's called on. It's what you do with the result that matters.

Comment: @user4581301: The Standard doesn't require that objects remain usable after a move, but it also doesn't require that implementations expend any effort in making them unusable.  Thus, in many cases, the fact that an object was moved will "get lost" immediately.

Comment: At runtime, yes. The situation is pretty much hopeless without heavy-duty non-standard extensions. I'm interested in whether or not the compiler can keep track. Trivial cases like move and use in the same scope it could handle. Maybe move and use in a simple chain of function calls. Global variables, good luck with that. Widely scoped variables and multiple threads, good luck. But between the extremes, how far could a compiler be reasonably expected to emit a warning should the compiler implementer choose to emit a warning?

Answer (score 1):

Some things that *may* help :

- Use a static analyzer. Xcode has it built-in.

  - https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/
- Use Address Sanitizer and Undefined Behaviour sanitizer

  - http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html
  - https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html

---

Code changes that can make such bugs easy to track down:

I'm assuming that if you're using `std::move` on something, it is (not always) a heavy container.

If so, try to use `std::unique_ptr<T>` to create it. Calls to movers must explicitly use `std::move`, which is easy to spot. And other non-owning access functions can just work with `.get()`. You can also check for nullability and throw if it's `nullptr` at any point where you need to access it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am aware that after using std::move the variable is still valid, but in an unspecified state.

This is not a universal truth. More generally, the object that was moved from is in whatever state in which the move constructor / assignment operator left it.

The standard library does have the guarantee that you describe at minimum. But it is also possible to implement a member function for your class which doesn't abide by it, and leaves the moved from object in an invalid state. It is however a good design choice to implement move operations in the way you describe.

> How to check if variable is still valid or std::move was used on it?

There is no way to do such check in general within the language.

> Is there any compiler option (in clang) or any way to throw an error either during runtime or compilation?

Note that using a variable after a move is not necessarily a bug at all, but can instead be an entirely correct thing to do. Some types specify exactly the state of the moved from object (`std::unique_ptr` for example) and others which have the validity guarantee can be used in ways that have no pre-conditions (such as calling `container.size()`).

As such, using a moved from object is only a problem if that violates a pre-condition, which would result in undefined behaviour. Clang and other compilers have runtime sanitisers that may be able to catch some undefined behaviour. There are also many warning options and static analysers that diagnose cases where bugs are likely.

Using them is a very good idea, but you should not rely solely on them because they won't be able to find all bugs. The programmer still needs to be careful when writing the program, and needs to compare it with the rules of the language. Following common idioms such as RAII, avoiding bare owning pointers (and other resource handles) goes a long way in avoiding typical bugs.